# Inner elements not targeted by SCSS with :hover selector:

Tags: html, sass

I'm trying to target an inner element with Sass using the :hover selector, but for some reason when using the partial selector with the underscore, the property gets ignored. The only workaround is to type the entire class name:

HTML:

```
    <div class="cds__grid">
        <div class="cds__card">
          <img src="images/content/image.svg">
          <div class="cds__card-overlay"> 
            <h4>A Title</h4>
            <p>Some Text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS:

```
.cds{
    &__grid{
        //Some Properties
    }

    &__card{
        &-overlay{
            background-color: grey;
        }

        &:hover{
            //Ignored
            &-overlay{
                background-color: blue; 
            }

            //Applied on Hover
            .cds__card-overlay{
                background-color: blue; 
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution, you need to add `&` after hover to keep reference of the parent class

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/harshitrastogi921/pen/qBjrEvB)

```css
.cds{
    &__grid{
        //Some Properties
    }

    &__card{          
        &-overlay{
            background-color: grey;
        }
        
        &:hover &{
            // Ignored
            &-overlay{
                background-color: blue; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="cds__grid">
    <div class="cds__card">
      <img src="images/content/image.svg">
      <div class="cds__card-overlay"> 
        <h4>A Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To understand why this is ignored it helps to learn more [about the ampersand in SCSS.](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/)

This is not some magic tool that sorts selectors, it just inserts the parent at the point where you write the `&`.

So if you write something like this:

```
.class {
  &:hover {
    &-detail {
   }
  }
}
```

This will be compiled into this:

```
.class {}
.class:hover {}
.class:hover-detail {}
```

Note the last selector, this is not a valid CSS selector, so this is why it get's ignored.

To achieve something like `.class-detail:hover` you would have to do something like this:

```
.class {
  &:hover {
  }
  &-detail {
    &:hover {
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply missed a } at the end of your code, and also an & sign to refer to your original element.
See in codepen.io: https://codepen.io/basescriptnet/pen/KKqWweo

```css
.cds{
    &__grid {
        //Some Properties
    }

    &__card{
        &-overlay {
            background-color: grey;
        }

        &:hover &{
            //Ignored
            &-overlay {
                background-color: blue; 
            }

            //Applied on Hover
            .cds__card-overlay {
                background-color: blue; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="cds__grid">
    <div class="cds__card">
      <img src="images/content/image.svg">
      <div class="cds__card-overlay"> 
        <h4>A Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Update**. I missed & sign after `:hover`, which led to wrong execution of the code. Instead of referring to parent, it was referring to `.cds__card:hover-overlay`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I checked your codepen, if you remove .cds__card-overlay{ background-color: blue; } the code won't work. Meaning that &-overlay will still be ignored.